# oracle sql: insert spatial data from more existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have created a table `umriss` which I filled with data and I still need to insert the geometry data from existing tables (`usrdemo.glets_1850`, `usrdemo.glets_1973`, ...). How does that work?

`umriss` is a "weak entity" and has references to the tables `gletscherstand` (`glst_id`) and `gletscher` (`gletscher_id`)

```
create table umriss
(
    umr_nr number (4) not null,
    umr_datum date,
    GLST_ID number (4) not null,
    shape mdsys.sdo_geometry,
    GLETSCHER_ID number (3) not null,
    se_anno_cad_data blob
);

alter table umriss
add constraint umriss_glst_pk
primary key (umr_nr, GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID);

ALTER TABLE umriss 
ADD CONSTRAINT umriss_gletscherstand_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID) 
REFERENCES GLETSCHERSTAND(GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID);
```

I manually inserted the data for the attributes `umr_nr`, `umr_datum`, `glst_id` and `gletscher_id`. As you can see from `umr_nr` there are 3 shapes and I now want to add the spatial data from `usrdemo_glets_1850` which has 3 shapes and the attributes: `objectid` (= `umr_nr` in table `umriss`), `shape` and `se_anno_cad_data`.

I tried this...

```
INSERT INTO umriss u
(u.shape, u.se_anno_cad_data) 
SELECT usrdemo.glets_1850.shape, usrdemo.glets_1850.se_anno_cad_data
FROM usrdemo.glets_1850;
```

> ...and got the message: Ora-01400 - cannot insert NULL into ..."umriss"."umr_nr"

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haved tried to insert new records into table `umriss` without setting values for the primary key column `umr_nr`.

If I have understood correctly, you have already manually inserted records into table `umriss`, and now what you need to do is to add addtional columns only, then you should use `UPDATE` instead.